# Laravel parse variable from Form to Controller method via Route

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel, laravel-routing

I'm trying to update an edit to a post without using the resource. I tried parsing the variable from my Form to my route using {id} but it gets ignored. This is the form I'm trying to post from.

```
{!! Form:: open(['action'=> ['ManageBooksController@updateBook', $book->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
  {{Form::label('Book_NAME', 'Name')}}
  {{Form::text('Book_NAME', $book->Book_NAME, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Name'])}}
</div>
{{Form::hidden('_method', PUT)}}
{{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!!Form:: close() !!}
```

This is my route

```
Route::put('manageBooks', 'ManageBooksController@updateBook');
```

This is my method in my controller

```
public function updateBook(Request $request, $id)
{

    $this->validate($request, ['Book_NAME' => 'required']);

    $books = Books::find($id);
    $books->Book_NAME =$request->input('Book_NAME');
    $books->save();

    return redirect('/manageBook')->with('success', 'Book Edited');
}
```

Comment: First thing to do is to change route to `Route::put('manageBooks/{id}', 'ManageBooksController@updateBook');`

Answer (score 0):

Your route is expecting a `PATCH`. Try updating your route to:

`Route::post('/manageBooks/{id}', 'ManageBooksController@updateBook');`

Or include the Laravel's `@method('PATCH')` within your form.

Also, your controller names don't match :)

Comment: Thanks I updated the error in my Controller name. I'm getting a MethodNotAllowedExcetion now ill try the @method('patch')

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing sequence of the arguments to the function:

```
public function updateBook($id, Request $request)  // Notice the sequence of the arguments
{
    ......
}
```

Comment: Give this a try, if you are getting all other POST data but not just the ID in the url. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Route, you have to specifics like this

```
{!! Form:: open(['route'=> ['manage_book', $book->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

In your route, you may need to name it properly

```
Route::post('/manageBooks/{id}', array('as'=>'manage_book','uses'=>'ManageBooksController@updateBook'));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Update without using resource :

your route :

`Route::get('/manageBooks', 'ManageBooksController@whateverer')->name('manageBooks');`

`Route::post('/manageBooks/{id}/edit', 'ManageBooksController@updateBook')->name('updateBook');`

your blade:

```
{!! Form:: open(['route'=> ['updateBook', $book->id], 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
  {{Form::label('Book_NAME', 'Name')}}
  {{Form::text('Book_NAME', $book->Book_NAME, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Name'])}}
</div>
{{Form::hidden('id', $book->id)}} //hidden field is not required
{{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!!Form:: close() !!}
```

your controller:

```
public function updateBook(Request $request, $id)
{

    $this->validate($request, ['Book_NAME' => 'required']);

    $books = Books::where('id',$id)->update(['Book_NAME'=>$request->Book_NAME]);
    return redirect()->route('manageBooks')->with('success', 'Book Edited');
}
```

Comment: I added this but i just get a blank page:(

Comment: return $books.chek output ;

Comment: you had created '/manageBook' route  without parameter or you are using same router of update ?

Comment: I just changed my question this is the closest i have got it working so it now gives my request to update but its missing my id parameter

Comment: you should go for form model https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html#form-model-binding

Comment: My URL structure goes /manageBooks/ then i click edit on a post which takes me too /manageBooks/1/edit then when i submit i get a parsing error with this url /manageBooks?

Comment: `Route::put('/manageBooks/{id}/edit', 'ManageBooksController@updateBook');` {id} is missing from url in your question

Comment: I try that and it gives me a 404 with /manageBooks//edit url its not picking up the id for some reason

Comment: what you declared any route before updateBook route like `Route::put('/manageBooks/{something}/{something}'`

Comment: I got an Idea in another hidden field I will send the id to the update method with only 1 parameter then take the id from whats sent and get that and  update my table that way  :)

Comment: why you are not using resource for crud operation

Answer (score 0):

In the end I added another hidden field where i parse the ID through of the post I'm editing. I also changed the find method to take the request variable pointing to the ID.

My Form:

```
{{Form::hidden('Book_ID', $book->Book_ID)}}
{{Form::hidden('_method', PUT)}}
{{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!!Form:: close() !!}
```

My function:

```
public function updateBook(Request $request)
{

$this->validate($request, ['Book_NAME' => 'required']);

$books = Books::find($request->Book_ID);
$books->Book_NAME =$request->input('Book_NAME');
$books->save();

return redirect('/manageBook')->with('success', 'Book Edited');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method POST to PUT in your from first,

```
{!! Form:: open(['action'=> ['ManageBooksController@updateBook', $book->id],'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('Book_NAME', 'Name')}}
    {{Form::text('Book_NAME', $book->Book_NAME, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Name'])}}
</div>
{{Form::submit('Submit', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!!Form:: close() !!}
```

Then You Have to Pass a parameter in your route, as your method expecting $id

```
Route::put('manageBooks/{id}/update', 'ManageBooksController@updateBook');
```